# writing prototype to check if string is uppercase

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

I am trying to write a string prototype that would check to see if a string is all uppercase or not. This is what I have so far and I am not sure why this does not work.

```
String.prototype.isUpperCase = function(string) {
  if(string === string.toUpperCase()) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
 }
}
```

I want it to work like this:

```
'hello'.isUpperCase() //false
'Hello'.isUpperCase() //false
'HELLO'.isUpperCase() //true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prototype method receives the instance in `this`, not the first argument as your code seems to expect. Try this:

```
String.prototype.isUpperCase = function() {
  return String(this) === this.toUpperCase();
}
```

The `String(this)` call makes sure that `this` is a string primitive and not a string object, which would not be recognized as equal with the `===` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the first argument (`undefined` in all three cases as you haven't passed any arguments) and not the string itself (which would be `this`, not `string`).

Comment: Okay that makes sense thank you for clearing that up!